# VB.NET Textbox remove all lines with 2 spaces or more

Tags: vb.net

So i have keywords on my text box that have 2 spaces or more

Example:

```
spotify premium apk
spotify login
spotify family
spotify mod apk
spotify apk
spotify app
spotify account
spotify apk mod
spotify app download
spotify apk download
spotify app for pc
```

what code should i use to remove all lines that have 2 spaces or more, i want to make my example into this.

```
spotify login
spotify family
spotify apk
spotify app
```

it will remove all lines that have 2 spaces or more

Comment: You can split each line by space character. if the number of items after splitting is more than two that means that line can be removed. This is the logic you need to implement in code. You use for each loop to loop thru the collection of lines and add the eligible lines to  a collection. You can use [RemoveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netframework-4.8) LINQ method also.

Comment: It's not for us to write your code for you. It's for you to research how to do what you want and then try to write code to do it. If the code doesn't work, then you show us what you did and describe exactly its behaviour differs from your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Any of these will find the lines for you (my order of preference):

```
Dim r = textBox.Lines.Where(Function(line) line.IndexOf(" "c) < line.LastIndexOf(" "c)).ToArray()

Dim r = textBox.Lines.Where(Function(line) line.Length - line.Replace(" ", "").Length > 1).ToArray()

Dim r = textBox.Lines.Where(Function(line) line.Split().Length > 2).ToArray()
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader as to get the lines back into the textbox

ps; you'll need to import System.Linq